# jquery make a div scroll?

Tags: jquery

How do I make a div scroll down by 1 px when a hash href is clicked.

```
    $('[href^="#"]').bind('click', function (e) {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                $('#freecontent') - 1;
            }, 500);
    });
```

i know the above doesnt work. #freecontent is the div and I want it to move down by 1px?

hTML:

```
<div id = "leftcontent">    
   <p>
      <p class ="currproj">
          <a  href="#24">Scunthorpe Footbridge</a>
      </p>                
      <p class ="currproj">
           <a  href="#27">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
      </p>                 
   </p> 
</div>   
<div id = "freecontent">
   <table>
       <tr> 
         <td>
           <a id="24"></a> 
         </td>
       </tr>                                 
       <tr> 
        <td>
          <a id="27"></a> 
        </td>
       </tr>                                 
  </table>                                         
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scrollTop();

e.g.

```
$('a').click(function(){

    $('div').scrollTop($('div').scrollTop() - 1);

});
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[href^="#"]').bind('click', function (e) {
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            $('#freecontent').css('top', '-= 1px');
        }, 500);
});
```

you can just simply change the css `top`

Comment: this doesn't scroll.. its changes the top value. If #freecontent has a set height and overflow:scroll then setting css top to -1px will only move the whole thing up, not scroll the content. Won't downvote, because although the question asks about scrolling it seems like the OP may have got his jargon wrong.